# How do I increase a number, stop it, use an if/else statement on C++?

Tags: c++

I am new to this community. So to elaborate on my question: I want to make a number start for 0 counting up to 10 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and then do an if statement saying if x <= 10 print "hello world". Followed by an else statement: else print "hello darkness my old friend".

Here is the code I put:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x += 2) {
    cout << x << endl;
    if (x = 20) {
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "hello darkness my old friend" << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that every time I run it, it always says:

```
0
hello world
```

What I want it to say is:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
hello world
```

Even if I change:

```
if (x = 10)
```

To:

```
if (x = *any number higher than 10*)
```

It still has the same output ALWAYS:

```
0
hello world
```

Please help me with this problem.

**EDIT:** I see that everyone is confused on the output I want. The out put I want is *if* the statement is true, print:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
hello world
```

**else, print:**

```
hello darkness my old friend
```

Comment: `=` is **assignment**. `==` is comparison. Turn on your compiler's warnings to the max and read them.

Comment: in your if(x = 20) statement it should be if(x == 10). this will not fix your problem fully but it is a start

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (int x = 0; x <= 20; x += 2) 
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        if (x == 10) 
        {
            cout << "hello world" << endl;
        }
        else if(x > 10)
        {
            cout << "hello darkness my old friend" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think this is what you want; I increased your loop limit to 20, fixed the comparison issue with `if(x ==10)` and I added and else `if(x > 10)` to take care of numbers greater than 10. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I Guess that's what you're looking for:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    //num taken from user
    if(num%2==0) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= num; x += 2) {
            cout << x << endl;
        }
        cout<<"Hello World" <<endl;
    } else {
        cout << "hello darkness my old friend" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Output will be like:-

```
let num=12;   //entered by USER 

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
Hello World

// In Case of False Condition

hello darkness my old friend
```

Comment: Also is there a way I can have the same output without asking the user for a number?

Comment: yes why not all you have to do is replace that "num" variable from for loops condition part and add a number till you want to print for example:- for(x=0; x<=12 ; x+=2)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the assignment/comparison issue, you loop will never reach any higher number than `10`, because that's when the loop condition says that the loop will end.

The statement `for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x += 2)` says to define and initialize `i` to `0`, loop while `x <= 10` is true, and after each iteration increase `x` by `2`. It is basically the same as this:

```
{
    int x = 0;
    while (x <= 10)
    {
        // Your code inside the loop
        x += 2;
    }
}
```

So you loop will have the following value for `x`: `0`, `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`, `10` and then after that `x <= 10` is false and the loop will end.

---

Coming back to the assignment/comparison issue, this is the reason some people like to write e.g. `20 == x` instead of `x == 20`. If by mistake assignment is used instead of comparison then the expression would be `20 = x` which is not a valid expression and the compiler would generate an error.

Most compilers today will be able to detect the assignment `x = 20` when used as a condition and can generate a warning for that. You might want to enable a higher warning level for the compiler to tell you about it.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you assigne 10 to x, so
 `(x=10) == true`

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried to fix it, and I made it count to 10, atleast.**
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x += 2) {
    cout << x << endl;
    if (x == 20) {
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "hello darkness my old friend" << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
0
hello darkness my old friend
2
hello darkness my old friend
4
hello darkness my old friend
6
hello darkness my old friend
8
hello darkness my old friend
10
hello darkness my old friend
```

Is this the result you needed?

Comment: No sorry. The output I wanted was that if the statement was true, print: 0 2 4 6 8 10 hello darkness my old friend. Else print: hello darkness my old friend (using if/else statement).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x += 2) 
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        if (x == 10)
            cout << "hello world" << endl;
        else 
            cout << "hello darkness my old friend" << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually works. Thanks! But what I would also want it where if the statement is correct to print "0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, hello world", but if the statement was wrong to print "hello darkness my old friend" with no numbers.

Comment: You asked something on the top and your example is different, please be clear about example what you want.

Comment: So the code you provided me was almost I wanted. So the output I wanted to see was that if it was successful to print: 0 2 4 6 8 10 hello world. But if it was unsuccessful, to print "hello darkness". So in short: if x = 10 print: 0 2 4 6 8 10 hello world. Else print: hello darkness my old friend".

Comment: then just add this line:   else  cout << "hello darkness my old friend" << endl;

Comment: But the output is:  "0
hello darkness my old friend
2
hello darkness my old friend
4
hello darkness my old friend
6
hello darkness my old friend
8
hello darkness my old friend
10
hello world". I would want it to print: "0 2 4 6 8 10 hello world" if the statement is true.If not (else statement) print: "hello darkness my old friend".